# Rotation of UISplitview in Tabbarcontrol

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a Tabbar control (as the root control).
In the first tab, I have a split view, which I programmatically created like so:

`UISplitViewController *split = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
                    split.navigationItem.title = @"All";`

MasterSplitViewController *root = [[[MasterSplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
                    root.navigationItem.title = @"Areas";
                    root.detailViewController = detail;

UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:root] autorelease];

split.tabBarItem = controller.tabBarItem;
split.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nav, detail, nil];
split.delegate = detail;

Everything works fine, except... If I start the app in Landscape mode, then the layout breaks a bit on the Master view.
If the app starts in Portrait, then I rotate to Landscape, then it is fine.
The only scenario when it breaks is when the app starts in Landscape.

When this happens, I check the console and see this message:
*Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.* BUT I am not using a two-stage rotation anywhere!! 
These 2 functions are overridden:

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`

Please see the attached screen shot.
http://img97.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110405at308.png/

Please help me. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem. 
Add this code to `AppDelegate.m`.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```